# Data conversion Nvarchar to Money

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion, currency

I have been browsing similar issues and can't seem to get a solution.

I have a file I am trying to insert into a current database format and have never had issues before.

I cannot cast some values as money.

Steps I have taken:
- Used isnull
- Replaced '-',' ',','
- Used the following that I found on a similar post:

```
SELECT [DocumentNo], [Amount in loc.curr.2]
FROM [Treasury_Tableau].[dbo].[Part1_Newdata_temp]
WHERE [Amount in loc.curr.2] LIKE '%[^-.0-9]%'
```

The above code helped me identify the following POTENTIAL (edited this in) "problem areas". There are no "blank" or null values that I can see....

```
DocumentNo  Amount in loc.curr.2
2000221487  -2.738732278E7
2000333953  -1.074E7
2000363822  -5.0E8
2000363827  -5.0E8
2000363801  -2.872375037E7
2000363804  -2.651213699E7
2000363729  -2.187203086E7
2000363793  -1.224149998E7
2000019151  2.738732278E7
2000005824  2.50904152E7
2000300876  -5.5E8
2000033083  5.5E8
2000033216  3.313527735E7
2000359252  -5.0E7
2000359260  5.0E7
6000000018  3.0E8
6000004586  -7.0E8
2000000053  -3.0E8
2000360503  1.514268022E7
6000000019  7.0E8
2000000054  -7.0E8
2000363908  -2.970673503E7
2101217911  1.311883095E7
2000363807  2.651213699E7
2000363735  2.872375037E7
2000363725  2.940657054E7
2000363730  2.970673503E7
2000363772  7.0E8
100000364            137039.69
2000318188         1085885.10
6000000216            45691.61
6000000216            45873.51
1400000032         8484903.17
2000000231           246059.97
2000000230           248343.93
2000347478             4686.74
2000000240             1883.17
2000360505             8020.17
2000360524            13171.80
2000000244            28115.65
2000031211           167589.00
2000363907             3314.52
2000363913             7479.00
2000000247            27837.00
2000000246           292309.29
2000000245           784942.75
```

When I copy to excel all these values read as numbers with decimal places perfectly fine. Not sure if it is now an issue with the exponential values??

Comment: Are you saying those values won't convert? `SELECT CONVERT(money,-2.738732278E7);` works fine for me. I'm not quite sure what you're asking here.

Comment: @Larnu I'm just trying to identify where my problem lies and why I keep getting "Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax." I'm doing spot checks and trying to convert but cannot find what the problem is

Comment: did you try this   SELECT CONVERT(money, convert(float, '-2.738732278E7')). if the value is string. you need first to convert into float then convert into money

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(money,'-2.738732278E7');` will generate that error (notice the single quotes). Treat your values as what they are, numbers, and you won't get the error. `'-2.738732278E7' <> -2.738732278E7`

Comment: Thank you. CONVERT(money, convert(float,[Amount in loc.curr.2])) all sorted!